# How can I solve the following optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following problem:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\max (x + y), \; \text{such that} \\ax + by ≤ 1 \\  x, y \geq 0\end{eqnarray}$$

For which values of $a$ and $b$ this problem is:

1. Infeasible
2. Unbounded
3. Has unique solution
4. Has infinite solution

I can solve the problem, but when occur to have to discover this kind of properties I am no good.

Comment: Hint: Break the values of $a$ and $b$ into cases like both positive, both negative, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: choose some values for a and b try to make a drawing of your problem